# How to get intent of a document using LDA or any Topic Modeling Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, lda, topic-modeling

I need to cluster a group of documents based on the intent they have and I am planning to use LDA(Latent Dirichlet Allocation - Topic Modeling).

Can i get intents to group the documents from topic modeling ? are there any other algorithms that cluster the documents based on the intents they have. Is this approach of using topic-modeling for intent clustering is good ?

I have been trying LDA Algorithm in topic modeling and able to get list of topics but not sure whether i can consider topics as intents itself.

Expecting an approach which clusters the group of documents based on the intents they have.

Comment: From what I've read, intents are most useful for Chatbots and action processing. They do not take into account topical information (usually filled with nouns and adjectives), but rather what the input intends to do (usually represented by verbs and adverbs). However, you have to consider your context and your application purpose, since it is what defines if intents are useful for modeling or not.

Comment: The context of my question is to classify emails of any inbox based on the content they have, this classification we thought of using topic modeling where we cannot get the context rather keywords. So to re pharse the question, whenever you get a new inbox as a dataset our application should do clustering and group the mails followed  by assignment of labels to the mails and training the classifier model to classify all the mails based on labels they have.

Comment: In this case, it seems that intent is important. For example, a salesman inbox may have several e-mails with the intent of a purchase and a businesmman inbox may have several informative e-mails, and so on. There are some ways to do it, such as identifying verbs, or using NLU tools. Play arround with AllenNLP tools and see if you can find something that intrests you. Check the demo: https://demo.allennlp.org/reading-comprehension

Answer (score 1):

as stated [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/lda2vec-topic-model) LDA disregards the structure of how words interact between each other, it will not be suited for intent modeling

> As a bag-of-words model is used to represent the documents, LDA can suffer from the same disadvantages as the bag-of-words model. The LDA model learns a document vector that predicts words inside of that document while disregarding any structure or how these words interact on a local level.

Consider the following to sentences:
This is his sister's dog (statement)
Is this his sister's dog (question)

Same words, different order, different intent.

You will probably need labeled data, and the use of neural networks such as CNNs or LSTMs.

Comment: Agreed, and if labeled data is scarce, there are some semi-supervised learning (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04870.pdf for Gmail intent detection) or even unsupervised approaches (https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00385)